# Pandas concat dataframes by values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm trying to create a dataframe using the values in two columns in a dataframe , this are how they look:

df1

```
W          F1        F2
0        'AB CD'   'RS TU'
0        'BC EF'   'GH IJ'
1        'BC EF'   'NO PQ'
0        'GH IJ'   'AB CD'
1        'KL MN'   'RS TU'
0        'NO PQ'   'UV WX'
...
```

df2

```
  F1         F2        BO_F1         BO_F2
'AB CD'   'GH IJ'       -150          500  
'BC EF'   'TG IP'        265         -150
'BC EF'   'NO PQ'       -500          250
'BC EF'   'GH IJ'        600         -700
'KL MN'   'PP UY'        150         -600 
'RS TU'   'AB CD'       -400          350
...
```

What I want:

```
W          F1        F2        BO_F1         BO_F2
0        'AB CD'   'RS TU'      -400          350
0        'BC EF'   'GH IJ'       600         -700
1        'BC EF'   'NO PQ'      -500          250
0        'GH IJ'   'AB CD'      -150          500
1        'KL MN'   'RS TU'      -600          700
0        'NO PQ'   'UV WX'       350         -900
```

I want to merge the columns `BO_F1` and `BO_F2` from df2 to df1 based on the values of columns `F1` and `F2`. The main problem I'm having is that some combinations of values are swapped, for example 
in df1 the first combination in `F1` and `F2` is `AB CD` and `RS TU` but such values in df2 are swapped, this is, `F1` and `F2` are `RS TU` and `AB CD`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you should clarify your question with a minimum working example. simplify your question and write some code that defines some dataframes that replicate your problem. it will make it easier to help

Comment: please tell me if my solution works

Answer (score 0):

df1.set_index('F1').join(df2.set_index('F2'))

Would this work? 
I'm not sure if I'm understanding the problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think if I'm understanding correctly you just care about merging observations based on the elements of the F1 and F2 columns, regardless of their order. Below I sort the F1 and F2 columns in both dataframes (sorting across columns not rows) and then I merge on these new columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
[0,        'AB CD',   'RS TU'],
[0,        'BC EF',   'GH IJ'],
[1,        'BC EF',   'NO PQ'],
[0,        'GH IJ',   'AB CD'],
[1,        'KL MN',   'RS TU'],
[0,        'NO PQ',   'UV WX']],
columns=['W', 'F1', 'F2']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
['AB CD',   'GH IJ', -150, 500],
['BC EF',   'TG IP', 265, -150],
['BC EF',   'NO PQ', -500, 250],
['BC EF',   'GH IJ', 600, -700],
['KL MN',   'PP UY', 150, -600],
['RS TU',   'AB CD', -400, 350]],
columns=['F1', 'F2', 'B0_F1', 'B0_F2']
)

ix1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df1[['F1', 'F2']].values, axis=1),
    columns=['F1', 'F2'])
df1_sorted = pd.concat([df1[[c for c in df1.columns if c not in ['F1', 'F2']]],
                 ix1], axis=1, sort=False)

ix2 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df2[['F1', 'F2']].values, axis=1),
    columns=['F1', 'F2'])
df2_sorted = pd.concat([df2[[c for c in df2.columns if c not in ['F1', 'F2']]],
                 ix2], axis=1, sort=False)

df3 = pd.merge(df1_sorted, df2_sorted, on=['F1', 'F2'], how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) 
independently for each value of `W`, then you can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df=df1.reset_index() # to sort values at the end
w_mask=df1['W'].eq(1)
new_df=pd.concat([df[w_mask].merge(df2,left_on=['F1','F2'],right_on=['F1','F2']),
                  df[~w_mask].merge(df2.rename(columns={'F1':'F2','F2':'F1'}),
                   left_on=['F1','F2'],
                   right_on=['F1','F2'])

          ]).sort_values('index').set_index('index')

print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
       W     F1     F2  BO_F1  BO_F2
index                               
0      0  AB CD  RS TU   -400    350
1      0  BC EF  GH IJ    600   -700
2      1  BC EF  NO PQ   -500    250
3      0  GH IJ  AB CD   -150    500
4      1  KL MN  RS TU   -600    700
5      0  NO PQ  UV WX    350   -900
```

---

**Sample DataFrame:**

```
    print(df1)
   W     F1     F2
0  0  AB CD  RS TU
1  0  BC EF  GH IJ
2  1  BC EF  NO PQ
3  0  GH IJ  AB CD
4  1  KL MN  RS TU
5  0  NO PQ  UV WX

print(df2)
      F1     F2  BO_F1  BO_F2
0  AB CD  GH IJ   -150    500
1  BC EF  TG IP    265   -150
2  BC EF  NO PQ   -500    250
3  BC EF  GH IJ    600   -700
4  KL MN  PP UY    150   -600
5  RS TU  AB CD   -400    350
6  KL MN  RS TU   -600    700
7  UV WX  NO PQ    350   -900
8  GH IJ  BC EF    600   -700
```

---

if there are rows in `F1` and `F2` of `df1` that do not index with `df2` and you do not want to lose them use `how = 'left'` in the [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method, or `how = 'outer'` if the lines present in df2 that are not in `df1` are also.

```
pd.concat([df[w_mask].merge(df2,left_on=['F1','F2'],right_on=['F1','F2'],how='left'),
           df[~w_mask].merge(df2.rename(columns={'F1':'F2','F2':'F1'}),
                   left_on=['F1','F2'],
                   right_on=['F1','F2'],
                   how='left')

          ]).sort_values('index').set_index('index')
```